# Cite an article from an old journal

Tags: citations

I want to cite the article on pages 29 - 30 from this journal:
https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/86583#page/7/mode/1up

The cover of the journal is:
[image]
So I created a bib-entry and have this:
[image]
But if I download the citation from the website https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/39008, I get:
[image]

So actually I would say that I can rely on these notes, but the author "Niels Bohr" is not named in the journal.
Is my attempt wrong?

Comment: Generally, trust your eyes over an automated citation generator. They're a convenience, not a truthtelling oracle.

Comment: @Anyon Thank you, this is very helpful! I always thought that these files are supervised, so that there is no mistake in it.

Comment: Lose the biodiversity site.  Why would you use anything other that the original publ8cation?

Comment: @ScottSeidman Because the original publication is from 1879, so it's not in stores anymore

Comment: @lereu - that has nothing to do with how yu cite it.

Comment: @ScottSeidman You asked why i use biodiversity. I suppose it's not a bad source and it's the same journal as I find elsewhere. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You don't need to cite where you got the article.  You need to  cite the article.  Proceedings articles are articles, not books.

Comment: Proper citation in MLA, from Google scholar: Pocklington, Henry C. "The determination of the prime or composite nature of large numbers by Fermat's theorem." Proc. Cambridge Philosophical Society, 1914 18 (1914): 29-30.

Comment: This paper is indexed in ZBmath, including a bibtex entry: https://zbmath.org/bibtex/02619247.bib

Answer (score 20):

The proper citation in MLA format is

> Pocklington, Henry C. "The determination of the prime or composite
> nature of large numbers by Fermat's theorem." Proc. Cambridge
> Philosophical Society, 1914 18 (1): 29-30.

Proc. Cambridge Philosophical Society is a journal, not a book, so the style you've chosen is incorrect.

Comment: I used @article in my bib-file.

Comment: @lereu.  Sorry.  The style bibtex or biber chose is incorrect, as "In:" suggests a book.

Comment: Which should I use then?

Comment: The one in this answer is correct.

Comment: Hm, this site tells me that the use of @article is correct (see the box in point 4): https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex#Enter_\(\mathrm{Bib\TeX}\)

Comment: @Lereu It's probably the bibliographic style (bst file) you're using and not the \@article that causes the "In" to render.

Comment: My guess is that the OP uses `biblatex`. For some reason, its default style uses 'In:" for journal articles as well.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with _in_, at least not semantically. You are citing a specific article which appeared ***in*** _this_ issue of _this_ journal. Sure, a book chapter is _in_ a book, but an article is also _in_ an issue. Yes, the _in_ can be elided, but I don't see why it would be wrong, as such. Not in accordance with MLA, possibly.

Comment: "In:", for journal articles, is not in MLA, APA, Chicago, Harvard, or Vancouver styles.

Answer (score 9):

The point of a citation is to make it possible for the reader to find the cited reference. The first one does just that.

Your paper is about mathematics. I wonder why your citation has a biodiversity URL. I would search for a better one. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test) offers https://archive.org/details/proceedingsofcam1718191316camb/page/28/mode/2up with the full text.

My guess would be that the physicist Neils Bohr appears in the second citation because he was one of the editors of these Proceedings, which cover many sciences.

Comment: I worry that my surveyor say "citation wrong".
And thank you for the hint, but does it matter from where the journal comes? The journal in your link is the same (and I try to avoid archive links).

Comment: The text of the citation tells the reader everything: Author, title, journal, pages. The URL is a bonus feature. Why not offer a link to the full text? You cold avoid the archive by finding the actual page at https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/108208#page/12/mode/1up . I might provide both URLs. I don't know who or what your "surveyor" is.

Comment: Surveyors are two profs in univerity that will review my thesis

Comment: Your surveyors will be just fine with the first citation, with any URL(s).

Answer (score 5):

The second bib-entry is clearly borked in several ways. Ignore it.

Comment: Strongly borked. It seems to be about a different paper: different year of publication, different page numbers, and different author(s).

Comment: This isn't really an answer. If you point out _how_ it's "borked", perhaps, but as it stands it is a comment. And not a very informative one, really. I mean, you're not wrong, but you don't tell anyone why you're right.

Comment: If @terdon's comment makes you want to include more details, you're welcome to use those in my first comment.